# Datetime.now as TimeSpan value?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, seconds

I need the current Datetime minus `myDate1` in seconds.

```
DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 9, 0, 0, 00);
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan myDateResult = new TimeSpan();

myDateResult = myDate2 - myDate1;
```

.
.
I tried different ways to calculate but to no effect.

```
TimeSpan mySpan = new TimeSpan(myDate2.Day, myDate2.Hour, myDate2.Minute, myDate2.Second);
```

.
The way it's calculated doesn't matter, the output should just be the difference these to values in seconds.

Comment: You don't need to do `myDateResult = new TimeSpan();` - you don't have to have an initializing expression for every variable and/or you could make the initializer the following expression.

Comment: @user1559441, you have already calculated the difference in TimeSpan `myDateResult`, you may use `TotalSeconds` property to get the difference in seconds

Comment: yeah, `.TotalSeconds` was the answer. thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your code is correct. You have the time difference as a `TimeSpan` value, so you only need to use the `TotalSeconds` property to get it as seconds:

```
DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 9, 0, 0, 00);
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan myDateResult;

myDateResult = myDate2 - myDate1;

double seconds = myDateResult.TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 47):

Code:

```
TimeSpan myDateResult = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: please use code markup (add 4 spaces before the code line), i'd edit it myself but it's such a tiny change that the system won't let me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it matches 100% the topic question.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried something like

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 9, 0, 0, 00)).TotalSeconds
```

[DateTime.Subtract Method (DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)

[TimeSpan.TotalSeconds Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
myDateResult.TotalSeconds
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds

Answer (score 2):

you need to get `.TotalSeconds` property of your timespan :

```
DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(2012, 8, 13, 0, 05, 00);
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan myDateResult = new TimeSpan();
myDateResult = myDate2 - myDate1;
MessageBox.Show(myDateResult.TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Subtract` method:

```
DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 9, 0, 0, 00);
DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = myDate2.Subtract(myDate1);
MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```c#
TimeSpan myDateResult;

myDateResult = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,9,0,0,00));
myDateResult.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```