# Comparing DateTime.Now to a Start and End time from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I've been struggling with this for hours and am sure there is a simple explanation.

I have a SQL Server table that contains the columns `DayOfWeek` (`DateTime`), `StartTime` (`Time`), `EndTime` (`Time`).

I am trying to write a lambda select that gets all the rows where `DateTime.Now` is the same `DayOfWeek`, greater than `StartTime` and less than `EndTime`.

I think I have to use the SQL Server type `Time` as C# `Timespan` but I'm just not getting it right.

I've tried to work from the explanation here ([Datetime.now as TimeSpan value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929554/datetime-now-as-timespan-value)) but to no avail.

My line of code is:

```
context.DayAndTimeModifiers
       .Where(x => x.IsActive && (int)d.DayOfWeek == x.DayOfWeek 
                   && d.??? > x.StartTime 
                   && d.??? < x.EndTime)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: d is DateTime.Now. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how I missed it, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay is what I needed.
Here's the adjusted line of code...

```
var d = DateTime.Now;

return context.DayAndTimeModifiers
              .Where(x => x.IsActive && (int)d.DayOfWeek == x.DayOfWeek && 
                          d.TimeOfDay > x.StartTime && d.TimeOfDay < x.EndTime).ToList();
```